# Best way for storing Java application name and version properties

Tags: java

Using Eclipse IDE.

I need to store my application's name and version as they are used by the app itself.
I could hard-code them as static final fields somewhere in the codebase. A better solution I know about may be storing them in the manifest file distributed with the application JAR.

Storing these properties in the manifest file feels better to me, but the problem is that the properties (obtained via Package methods) are not accessible during the development phase - running/debugging from IDE.

Is there a way to define them in Eclipse Run/Debug configurations? Is there a better way of storing such pieces of information. (I can also imagine using the Preferences API, although they are not "preferences" per se).

Thanks.

Comment: You create a standard properties file or even an XML file which could be stored as part of the application resources and packaged with the Jar when you bundle it, but would be available at dev time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use properties file. Here is a good start: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/